# Modular SELECT statements in Drizzle ORM

Tags: sql, typescript, next.js, drizzle

I have a function that queries a database using Drizzle ORM and accepts various options, such as `enabled`, `limit`, and potentially more in the future. I'm looking for a more concise and modular way to handle these options in my function.

Here's the current implementation:

```
type Options = {
    enabled?: boolean,
    limit?: number,
    // Potentially more options in the future
}

async function getAddresses(contactId: number, options: Options): Promise<InferSelectModel<typeof addressSchema>[]> {
    if (options.enabled !== undefined && options.limit) {
        return db.select().from(addressSchema).where(and(eq(addressSchema.contactId, contactId), eq(addressSchema.enabled, options.enabled))).limit(options.limit)
    } else if (options.enabled !== undefined && options.limit === 0) {
        return db.select().from(addressSchema).where(and(eq(addressSchema.contactId, contactId), eq(addressSchema.enabled, options.enabled)))
    } else if (options.limit) {
        return db.select().from(addressSchema).where(eq(addressSchema.contactId, contactId)).limit(options.limit)
    } else {
        return db.select().from(addressSchema).where(and(eq(addressSchema.contactId, contactId))
    }
}
```

I'd like to simplify this code while using Drizzle ORM, make it more modular, and prepare for potential future options (e.g., an offset option). How can I achieve a more elegant and maintainable solution with Drizzle ORM?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use dynamic query building as demonstrated in the drizzle docs:
https://orm.drizzle.team/docs/dynamic-query-building

Define a function for each parameter you want to conditionally apply, e.g.

```
function withLimit<T extends PgSelect>(qb: T, limit) {
  if (limit !== undefined) {
    return qb.limit(limit)
  }
  return qb
}
```

Then you can build up your query by applying each function, e.g.

```
let qb = db.select().from(addressSchema).$dynamic()
qb = withLimit(qb, options.limit)
// use await qb or qb.then to get your result
```

Comment: This was helpful. Do you know when drizzle actually executes the query? The `.run()` obviously executes synchronously. However it seems like most async queries are awaited, for the response. What's stopping me from chaining new methods (keeping in mind that I can only use a method once per statement) and modifying the base query, and just awaiting the result at the end?

Comment: @sayandcode the drizzle query builder objects implement the Promise<T> interface and executes itself when you `await` it, or call `then` or `finally`. The query will not execute before that. You can see how that works in the source code: https://github.com/drizzle-team/drizzle-orm/blob/0d833d1ca78735e29b124e2a672bda2c85738f48/drizzle-orm/src/query-promise.ts

Comment: Thy, this is working fine for me. Do you know what type deflation is for postgresql schemas?

Comment: @hantoren sorry, I don't really know much about Drizzle, I just happened to be reading the docs when I came across this unanswered post.